# Is there a way to use Soft Assert to be able to verify if the text contains a certain string

Tags: selenium, appium

I do not want to use Assert as it would be a hard fail in case it does not find a match. So I am looking to use Soft Assert. But in my scenario I need to check if there is a partial text match. Please help.

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: Can you clear more on which tools are you using? If you are using TestNG, it has softassert and for the partial text match you can use string contains. For reference:

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/soft-asserts-in-testng-example

Comment: It could be done for example with AssertJ matches and regex: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(S|s)ome string"); assertThat("Some string").matches(pattern);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can follow the below approach.
Think your actual text is "Business process ID: 123456 has been updated", and you want to check whether it contains only the "has been updated" partial string.

```
String actual = "Business process ID: 123456 has been updated";
String partial = "has been updated";
softAssert.assertTrue(actual.contains(partial), "partial string is not contained in the given text");
softAssert.assertAll();
```